# Back to the silver leaf maple

Tags: maple

I read the remarks about the silver maple - and wondering: There is a silver maple in our town, street side, that may be 150 to 200 years old. Huge! Developers want to take it down to, as Joni Mitchell sang "...put up a parking lot.'' Is the tree likely to live much longer anyway, or should we let it go?

Comment: "In ideal natural conditions, A. saccharinum may live up 130 years, but in urban environments often 80 or less." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_saccharinum What sort of shape is the tree in?

Comment: Could we please have a picture of this grand tree? Is it A saccharinum or another maple? It would be a shame to lose such a local tree. If you can find old pictures of this, maybe you can fight the developers and get this noted to be a special specimen. If it's integral to the locality and community it would add to your case to be kept or at least incorporated into any design in a sensible and sensitive way.  Good luck

Comment: Edited to make it a little less opinion based. I think if we have a picture this question could now reasonably be answered as 'yes this tree has life left in it' or 'no this tree will die soon anyway.'